# Exposing RabbitMQ AMQP port using ingress nginx

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, kubernetes-ingress, bitnami

After research for a few days, I assume [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61430311/exposing-multiple-tcp-udp-services-using-a-single-loadbalancer-on-k8s) is the most valuable answer for now, and I was tried to find my way out from that idea, just forward tcp protocol from the port to the corresponding service. But I have no luck so far.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

**Environment:**

- Ubuntu 22.04
- K3s
- [Nginx](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx) installed, using helm, namespace `ingress-nginx`
- RabbitMQ installed using [bitnami chart](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/rabbitmq), namespace `rabbitmq`

###### First weird behavior

After using port-forwarding to check whether we're able to connect to 5672

```bash
# Allow 5672/tcp port accessible from everywhere
ufw allow 5672/tcp

# port forwarding
kubectl port-forward rabbitmq-0 5672:5672

# Checking connection success from local
telnet localhost 5672

# Checking connection failed from any other machine
telnet <my-vps-ip> 5672
```

I'm sure there's no other firewall, as I only use ufw command to expose other ports, they all work fine.

Any idea ?

###### Forward TCP request via nginx ingress

[image: ingress-nginx-controller deploy TCP config map added]
`--tcp-services-configmap` flag within `ingress-nginx-controller` deployments being added

[image: RabbitMQ service locate]

[image: Config map added]
Config map with port 5672 added.

[image: Target port added to ingress-nginx-controller deployment]

Checking port 5672 was also patched within `ingress-nginx-controller` deployment, using command `kubectl get deploy ingress-nginx-controller -n ingress-nginx -o yaml`

[image: ingress-nginx-controller ingress service updated]

Checking port 5672 was also patched within `ingress-nginx-controller` service, using command `kubectl get svc ingress-nginx-controller -n ingress-nginx -o yaml`

But now, even testing locally failed by command `telnet localhost 5672`, which previously success using port forward.

Is that I missed something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up using a load balancer service for it. Here's how it does

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: amqp-expose
  namespace: rabbitmq
spec:
  ports:
    - name: amqp
      protocol: TCP
      port: 5672
      targetPort: 5672
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: rabbitmq
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: rabbitmq
  type: LoadBalancer
  sessionAffinity: None
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
```